# drawing lines in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I have created an sos app in which i am able to see the position coordinates of a person who have my app in their phone but now i want to integrate google maps with it so that i may able that when a person hits sos button so it triggers another activity which will be googlemap activity and in that activity i want ti draw line from that person position to my server position and i should be able to count the distance from that person to me. any suggestions how can i achieve this? please i am new to google maps guide me through this i have searched the internet but i didn't got the required results.

Comment: do you want a straigth line or a routing line? In the first case, just look at Gmaps samples, in the second case you have to look at directions api

Comment: can i have your skype id please???

Comment: Full of the same question in stackoverflow. Check at those https://www.google.it/search?q=stackoverflow+android+google+maps+routing&oq=stackoverflow+android+google+maps+routing&aqs=chrome..69i57.11696j0j4&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thank you :) in case if i need more help can i have your skype please?